# What is the German translation of the singular "they/them"?

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun, gender-neutrality

With the actual translation of "them/they" being "sie/ihr" which is exactly the same as the singular female pronoun "sie/ihr", is there a generally accepted alternative in german?

As in, how would you translate "I met them at a party" when referring to a single person?

Comment: There is no generally accepted alternative. Instead we have many alternatives with very little acceptance (including the opinion that you shouldn't genericize at all).

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/in-contracts-which-pronoun-to-use-when-referring-back-to-e-g-der-verk%c3%a4ufer

Comment: If you talk about a person you met at a party you wouldnt use a neutral pronoun. You would say i met her/ him.

Comment: @Alex Sure, if it is a female or male person. But I wouldn't adress someone identifying as non-binary as him/her. I think the question that is duplicated by mine goes into the direction I was asking bit sure how I missed that one...

Comment: @AramBecker Well I guess if the person in question does not want to be addressed by him/ her you would use the pronouns that person chose/ invented for them. If that was not part of their discussion and you dont know their pronouns, that kinda makes a good point why the vast majority rejects this idea/ movement.